Is the term 標準語 considered sensitive in modern Japan?
I have read somewhere (perhaps in a Japanese book, I forgot) that the term 標準語 was sensitive to older generations, because at the time of the process of standardization of the language, the dialect written by the Tokyo upper-class was treated as superior to other dialects. Was this ever true, and if so, is this still the case? If it isn't the case anymore, when did the word lose its sensitive aspect? Should I be wary of using that word among older people?

Designating a certain Tokyo dialect as 標準語 itself wasn't a significant problem. However, from the mid-Meiji period to shortly after WWII, the government actively suppressed other dialects and enforced the use of 標準語. This had practical reasons in those days, since media like radio were not yet widespread, and communication between people from different areas could be really difficult. As a result, 方言 was generally viewed much more negatively than 標準語, but some people naturally grew to dislike the term 標準語 as a backlash against this enforced standardization. This means, in my opinion, there is little reason to regard only either of 方言 and 標準語 as "historically sensitive".
It's been a long time since such dialect suppression policies ended, and almost no one today speaks with accents strong enough to hinder communication. Therefore, nowadays, very few people perceive any negative connotations with either 方言 or 標準語. Instead of 標準語, some communities prefer the term 共通語, indicating a de facto standard language rather than a formally standardized one. However, there is little practical difference between 標準語 and 共通語 in Japanese, and the former remains the term used more often by the general public.
References:

標準語: 各言語における標準語: 日本語 - Wikipedia
日本の方言: 近代以降 - Wikipedia

明治になって言葉の統一が求められるようになると、東京方言をもとに標準語を確立し普及させようとする動きが起こった。同時に、方言を排除しようとする動きが広がり、標準語こそが正しい日本語であり、方言は矯正されなければならない「悪い言葉」「恥ずかしい言葉」とみなされた。昭和40年代ごろまで、方言撲滅を目的の一つとする標準語教育が各地の学校で行われ、中には地域・家庭ぐるみで自発的に方言追放活動を推進するところもあった。


方言札 - Wikipedia
「共通語」と「標準語」はどのように違うのですか


+1 for sharing references directly, I love seeing this! Fantastic answer as usual.
